# Maven nexus with jetty 7 and apache2 reverse proxy

Tags: apache2, maven, jetty, reverse-proxy, nexus

Here is my problem : i try to run a maven nexus behind an apache reverse proxy. As i have multiples war in my jetty, i want the nexus to run here :

http://localhost:8080/nexus

I made a jetty context file as follow : {jetty.home}/contexts/nexus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="contextPath">/nexus</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/nexus.war</Set>

</Configure>
```

My jetty connector in jetty.xml is as follow :

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="forwarded">true</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

I want http://maven.foo.com/ as an end point for the nexus, so i made this apache2 configuration file :

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
  AddDefaultCharset off
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
             ServerName maven.foo.com

             ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/nexus/
             ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/nexus/

             ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_nexus.log
</VirtualHost>
```

But i can't manage to make it work. The error message displayed in the browser is "The server has not found anything matching the request URI". I tried to read docs on jetty and apache web site, but didn't find information for mapping a subdomain "sub.foo.com" to a context "localhost:8080/sub" ...

Any help welcome ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jetty you can configure a particular web-app to be served as the root (default) application on a particular sub-domain by following these instructions

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts

If you do that, then your Apache proxy config should become pretty simple.